# Visitor's visa refusal

Tags: visa-refusals

If I invite someone to the UK for graduation and the person is refused a visa, does it affect me in any way in my own future application? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

No, it won't affect your personal visa applications but it may affect your viability as a sponsor for future applications, especially if this repeats many times.